# Experiencing high latency with server without any server load nor local router latency

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing, latency

I am experiencing a very weird issue and it is hard to synthesize in a simple sentence, so I am sorry if the title of the question is rather shady.

So I have a dedicated server running with the following specs:

CPU: Intel i5-4590 Quad-Core @ 3.3Ghz
RAM: 4x 8Gb(32Gb total)
SSD: 2x500 Gb SSD
OS: Ubuntu server LTS 16.04

So when I ping my server, this is what I get:

```
Envoi d’une requête 'Ping'  85.25.185.108 avec 32 octets de données :
Réponse de 85.25.185.108 : octets=32 temps=54 ms TTL=55
Réponse de 85.25.185.108 : octets=32 temps=108 ms TTL=55
Réponse de 85.25.185.108 : octets=32 temps=117 ms TTL=55
Réponse de 85.25.185.108 : octets=32 temps=76 ms TTL=55

Statistiques Ping pour 85.25.185.108:
    Paquets : envoyés = 4, reçus = 4, perdus = 0 (perte 0%),
Durée approximative des boucles en millisecondes :
    Minimum = 54ms, Maximum = 117ms, Moyenne = 88ms
```

As you can see the latency is weirdly going up and down.

Now, the server currently has a CPU load of 33% and a memory load of 11.8Gb over the 32 Gb.

I have asked a mate to try and he doesn't experience any latency whatsoever and has very low ping to the server, so apparently, I am the only one experience this issue.

Now if I do a tracert to the server:

```
  1    <1 ms     1 ms     2 ms  FREEBOX [x.x.x.x]
  2    34 ms    31 ms    32 ms  cnv94-2-x-x-x-x.fbx.proxad.net [x.x.x.x]
  3    40 ms    31 ms    44 ms  213.228.14.254
  4   116 ms   109 ms   101 ms  bzn-crs16-2-be1008.intf.routers.proxad.net [194.149.160.125]
  5    97 ms    86 ms   110 ms  th2-9k-3-be1000.intf.routers.proxad.net [194.149.163.90]
  6    68 ms    71 ms    77 ms  be4204.ccr31.par04.atlas.cogentco.com [149.11.115.13]
  7   107 ms   107 ms   110 ms  be3184.ccr42.par01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.38.157]
  8    82 ms    48 ms    38 ms  be2247.rcr21.sxb01.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.49.117]
  9    62 ms    61 ms    70 ms  be2781.nr14.b015623-2.sxb01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.25.8.234]
 10   116 ms    66 ms    42 ms  149.14.12.82
 11    98 ms    78 ms    61 ms  malta2027.startdedicated.net [85.25.185.108]
```

Now my router displays a total traffic load as:

```
  Download: 55Ko/s (6.5Mb/s max)
  Upload: 6Ko/s (1.0Mb/s max)
```

I have tried doing an MTR from the server to bing.com and got this:

```
PING bing.com (204.79.197.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=3.88 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=2 ttl=120 time=3.87 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=3 ttl=120 time=3.87 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=4 ttl=120 time=3.95 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=5 ttl=120 time=4.06 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=6 ttl=120 time=4.21 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=7 ttl=120 time=3.76 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=8 ttl=120 time=4.16 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=9 ttl=120 time=4.18 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=10 ttl=120 time=4.33 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=11 ttl=120 time=4.03 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=12 ttl=120 time=3.93 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=13 ttl=120 time=4.27 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=14 ttl=120 time=3.92 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=15 ttl=120 time=4.08 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=16 ttl=120 time=3.89 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=17 ttl=120 time=4.13 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=18 ttl=120 time=4.05 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=19 ttl=120 time=4.00 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=20 ttl=120 time=3.88 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=21 ttl=120 time=4.02 ms
64 bytes from a-0001.a-msedge.net (204.79.197.200): icmp_seq=22 ttl=120 time=3.93 ms
```

So now, I'm starting to believe there is a faulty node on my route to the server, does anyone have any idea what's going on and how to fix this please?

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bad "hope"-way to your server. Between you and your server theris some bad route that give such issue. So it's not the server problem, it's yor ISP problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know how to call it but this must be it. What can I do to improve this issue?
I used to work at the HQ of my ISP so I have a few contacts inside I can call. I'm a developer so I have only little knowledge of networking and networks infrastructure.

Comment: Oh i think you can't improve it so simple, you know its routing protocols and usually they choose next hope automatically by latency or bandwidth. So i don't belive that ISP change something only for one client. As alternatively you can connect to VPN and work over this network. In this case you need VPN to server wich have good latency both whith your ISP and server that you need.

Comment: Thanks, could you recommend any solid, secure and reliable VPN service (even with a fee) please? I've always been interested in using one and it seems you may have the information I need to get started.

Comment: Nope, cause i am sysadmin and love linux, so i always instal and configure own vpn, so my sugestion is OpenVPN for you, your just need virtual server or another pc in other ISP in your town=)

Comment: You should anyway report this to your ISP, since it affects the quality of their service, and therefore they would be glad to know that the issue exists. They might be able to change something on their end to fix it.